# What is the equivalent command in openssl to API of DES_ncbc_encrypt?

Tags: c++, openssl

Suppose I have this command in shell

```
> echo -n "abc" | openssl enc -e -K 4a08805813ad4689 -iv 1112131415161718 -des-cbc -a -p -v
salt=E0BE670000000000
key=4A08805813AD4689
iv =1112131415161718
lb5mBZNE/nU=
bytes read   :       3
bytes written:      13

> echo -n "abc" | openssl enc -e -K 4a08805813ad4689 -iv fadced8beb69425b -des-cbc -a -p -v
salt=E0BE670000000000
key=4A08805813AD4689
iv =FADCED8BEB69425B
XXlljYbfJYg=
bytes read   :       3
bytes written:      13
```

and the c++ code

```
#include <string.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/des.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

int b64encode(char* in, int in_len, char* out, int out_cap_len);
int b64decode(char* in, int in_len, char* out, int out_cap_len);
int b64code(char* in, int in_len, char* out, int out_cap_len, bool way);

int b64encode(char* in, int in_len, char* out, int out_cap_len)
{
    return b64code(in, in_len, out, out_cap_len, true);
}

int b64decode(char* in, int in_len, char* out, int out_cap_len)
{
    return b64code(in, in_len, out, out_cap_len, false);
}

int b64code(char* in, int in_len, char* out, int out_cap_len, bool way)
{
    BIO* b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    BIO_set_flags(b64, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);
    BIO* bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    BIO_push(b64, bio);
    int out_len = 0;
    if (way)
    {
        BIO_write(b64, in, in_len);
        BIO_flush(b64);
        out_len = BIO_read(bio, out, out_cap_len);
    }
    else
    {
        BIO_write(bio, in, in_len);
        BIO_flush(bio);
        out_len = BIO_read(b64, out, out_cap_len);
    }
    BIO_free_all(b64);
    return out_len;
}

void hexdump(unsigned char* ptr, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        printf("%02x", *(ptr + i));
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string text("abc");
    unsigned char cipher[1024] = "";
    DES_key_schedule schedule;
    DES_cblock key = { 0x4a, 0x08, 0x80, 0x58, 0x13, 0xad, 0x46, 0x89 };
    DES_cblock ivec = { 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18 };
    DES_set_key_checked(&key, &schedule);
    printf("initialized:\n");
    printf("key=");
    hexdump(key, sizeof key);
    printf("iv =");
    hexdump(ivec, sizeof ivec);
    DES_ncbc_encrypt((unsigned char*)text.c_str(), cipher, (long)text.length(), &schedule, &ivec, DES_ENCRYPT);
    printf("updated:\n");
    printf("key=");
    hexdump(key, sizeof key);
    printf("iv =");
    hexdump(ivec, sizeof ivec);
    char b64encoded[1024] = "";
    b64encode((char*)cipher, strlen((char*)cipher), b64encoded, sizeof b64encoded - 1);
    std::cout << b64encoded << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Then I build and run it

```
> g++ -o zdex.bex zdes.cpp -lcrypto && ./zdex.bex
initialized:
key=4a08805813ad4689
iv =1112131415161718
updated:
key=4a08805813ad4689
iv =fadced8beb69425b
+tzti+tpQls=
```

So if I want to get the identical result `+tzti+tpQls=` using `openssl` utility, how to change the way using it, do I need to change the endianness of `key` or `iv` or maybe the cipher name I don't know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

There is no way to do that since `openssl` utility requires *multiple of block length* input data.

In the c++ code calling `DES_ncbc_encrypt("abc", ...)` the input clear-text is `"abc"`, but passing "abc" to `openssl` utility the input clear-text with padding attached to be `"abc\x05\x05\x05\x05\x05"`, which means it it calling `DES_ncbc_encrypt("abc\x05\x05\x05\x05\x05", ...)`, it is just because `openssl` utility used *envelope mode* to call `DES_ncbc_encrypt` function instead of calling `DES_ncbc_encrypt` directly, *EVP_* mode* did the padding work.

But in the case of input clear-text is *multiple of block length* already, you can use the `-nopad` in the `openssl` utility command to disable EVP auto-padding procedure, only if in such way, we will get the identical results.